# Ошибка в gulp: dest.on is not a function?

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass, gulp-watch

Gulpfile с гитхаба, у меня выдает ошибку в таске sass:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам файл: https://github.com/agragregra/gulp-lesson/blob/master/gulpfile.js

Answer (score 0):

Версия gulp у вас скорее всего старая, нужно установить >= 4.0.0
Как обновить?
Примерно так

```
npm install gulpjs/gulp#4.0 --save-dev
```